# Ignore methods by the php interpretor

Tags: php-5.3

It is possible in php to ignore some methods by the php interpretor? I need to ignore some methods or functions if the project is, for example, in the release mode, and executed them if  the project is in the debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you're indeed talking about methods (not functions) then the solution is using [Overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

```
class MyClass
{
  static public $debugging = true;

  public function __call($function, $arguments)
  {
    if (!self::$debugging)
      trigger_error("Cannot call $function in release mode!", E_USER_ERROR);
    return call_user_func_array(array($this,'__real_'.$function), $arguments);
  }

  protected function __real_debug($a,$b,$c)
  {
  // Do something here
  }
}
```

Then for all not implicitly declared methods of `MyClass`, the overloaded `__call` method will be invoked. If you do:

```
$c = new MyClass();
$c->debug(1,2,3);
```

Then, if `$debugging` is true, the protected `__real_debug` is called.

BTW: the above sample is not restricted to PHP 5.3. It works for any PHP 5.x version.

Comment: I also thought about this solution, but I was trying to avoid using an if statement every time I want to do some debuging stuff.

Comment: Then use different base classes. Maybe have a MyClassDebug and MyClassRelease and instantiate accordingly?

I see no other solution, since #ifdefs (like in C) aren't implemented in PHP...